# I need to calculate the average of the numbers that the user writes, but when I try it tells me that the average is always 0

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio

I need to calculate the average of the numbers that the user writes, but when I try it tells me that the average is always 0.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    float Prices[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    int n, Avr, i;
    float PrzVar;

    do {

        cout << "Inserire la quantit" << (char)133 << " di prezzi di cui fare la media: ";
        cin >> n;

    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 10);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        cout << "Inserire il " << i + 1 << (char)167 << " prezzo: ";
        cin >> Prices[i];

    }

    PrzVar = Prices[i];
    Avr = PrzVar / n;

    cout << "La media dei prezzi inseriti corrisponde a: " << Avr;

}
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly how `PrzVar = Prices[i]; Avr = PrzVar / n;` is supposed to calculate the average price? Usually an average would involve a sum of some kind.

Comment: `PrzVar = Prices[i];` - set a breakpoint here. What is `i`?

Comment: Also `n` seems to be `int`, producing an integer division, you need to cast it to `float`.

Comment: @RaymondChen i set the breakpoint and it tells me that i is equals 5

Comment: @NathanPierson i need to know how to make the sum of the numbers in the array

Comment: Notice that `i` is 5, but you filled only entries `0` through `4`, so `Prices[5]` is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Average of n numbers = (Sum of numbers)/(Number of numbers);

In your code, these are the issues:

1. I guess you intended to use `PrzVar` to store sum, however you placed it outside of loop.
2. Also `PrzVar` has to be initialized to `0`
3. Your final answer is stored in `Avr` but it is an integer, so you may get some rounding off in some cases

Here is the fixed code.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    float Prices[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    int n;
    float PrzVar = 0; // Initialize sum variable to 0

    do {

        cout << "Inserire la quantit" << (char)133 << " di prezzi di cui fare la media: ";
        cin >> n;

    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        cout << "Inserire il " << i + 1 << (char)167 << " prezzo: ";
        cin >> Prices[i];
        PrzVar += Prices[i]; //move this into the loop
    
    }

    float Avr = PrzVar / n;

    cout << "La media dei prezzi inseriti corrisponde a: " << Avr;

}
```

Comment: You should move the declarations of `i`, `PrzVar` and `Avr` to `float PrzVar = 0; for (int i = ...)` and `float Avr = PrzVar / n`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant to increment PrzVar with the value of Prices[i] inside the for loop and then divide it? Currently you are setting it to 0, because i has been incremented in the for loop to the value of n (which will be either 0 or exception that no element exists in this program)

If thats  the case you should consider declaring variables inside the for loops to avoid further confusion. Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: i did it but now the program doesn't run, maybe because I already declared the variable I first?